# how can i save React single page as HTML when i click on Save as HTML instead for right click on Browser and save it

Tags: javascript, html, save

1. I have added on button Save as HTML and when i click on it button then my webpage download as a html instead of right click on Browser and save it.
2. when i right click on browser and save it exactly similar process done by clicking on button from my web page.
3. so please give me live example or solution for it

Comment: Hi Kevin and welcome on SO, if you want to see your question answered I suggest you read: [ask], [help].

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have the following HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Save Demo</title>
</head>

<body>
    <p>Hello World</p>
    <button id="save-btn">Save as HTML</button>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

You want to download the page as an HTML file when the user clicks on the button.

First, lets create a reusable download function that accepts a string `filename`, and a string `contents`, and creates a file named `filename` that contains `contents`.

```
function download(filename, contents) {
  // Create an anchor tag to download the file
  const anchor = document.createElement('a');
  // Create an href that contains the contents of the file
  // encodeURIComponent encodes a text string as a valid component of a URI
  anchor.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(contents));
  // set the download attribute to download the given filename
  anchor.setAttribute('download', filename);
  // Anchor tag should be invisible
  anchor.style.display = 'none';
  document.body.appendChild(anchor);
  // Fire the event
  anchor.click();
  // Remove the anchor tag
  document.body.removeChild(anchor);
}
```

Given a filename of `"helloworld.txt"` and contents of `"This is a really cool text file"` the function will download a file helloworld.txt with the given contents.

Now we just need to create an event listener on the button to download the html when it's clicked.

```
const btn = document.querySelector('#save-btn');

btn.addEventListener('click', (evt) => {
  // create a container for the html
  const container = document.createElement('div');
  // create an html element
  const html = document.createElement('html');
  // set the inner html of the html element to be the inner html of the document (everything except the <html></html>)
  html.innerHTML = document.documentElement.innerHTML;
  // append the html element to the container, to keep the <html></html>
  container.appendChild(html);
  // download the file as index.html
  download('index.html', container.innerHTML);
});
```

This will download a file that contains everything in the HTML file except for `<!DOCTYPE html>`, which you could add by calling `download` as such:

```
download('index.html', '<!DOCTYPE html>' + container.innerHTML);
```